# change of variables in double integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

[image]

I am having conflict in the end as you see .How do i resolve this ? THANKS

Comment: Jacobian is missing. You can start there.

Comment: No it is not main concern here as you can see it is 1/2 i  all options so

Comment: Did you try sketching the region in the $xy$-plane and the $uv$-plane?

Comment: You see u-v=1 and u-v =-2 ,

Comment: for x=1 its seems you multiply the LHS by two (to rid yourself of the fractions) but do not multiply your RHS by two.

Comment: But stillregio in uv plane is not clear to me

Comment: @SophieClad, you didn't have that image before. I suggest you let $x  = y = 0$ to begin sketching.